# Are there any reasons to ensure account existence through incrementing account's references?

Tags: pallet, account

As we know from [this doc](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/account-data-structures/#account-reference-counters), account get reaped when it's consumers/providers/sufficients (all of them) reference count decreased to 0. These counters described as:

```rust
  /// The number of other modules that currently depend on this account's existence. The account
  /// cannot be reaped until this is zero.
  pub consumers: RefCount,
  /// The number of other modules that allow this account to exist. The account may not be reaped
  /// until this and `sufficients` are both zero.
  pub providers: RefCount,
  /// The number of modules that allow this account to exist for their own purposes only. The
  /// account may not be reaped until this and `providers` are both zero.
  pub sufficients: RefCount,
```

Suppose that we have a pallet that has storage map `AccountId -> SomeData`. And in this pallet we could increment some of the references counts mentioned above to keep account alive until we descrease this. Let's consider a case when we don't do this. The questions are the following:

1. Are there any differences between account that was reaped and then endowed again and account that was not reaped because we added a reference?
2. When we **really should** modify these counters in our pallets?

Answer (score 1):

1- No, unless you scan the blockchain to see all the events related to that account you won't know if has been reaped before.

> Having an account go below the existential deposit causes that account
> to be reaped. The account will be wiped from the blockchain's state to
> conserve space, along with any funds in that address. You do not lose
> access to the reaped address - as long as you have your private key or
> recovery phrase, you can still use the address - but it needs a top-up
> of another existential deposit to be able to interact with the chain.

This is how the clean up of the account works under the hood: [How does Substrate clean up accounts whose balance is below the existential deposit?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4964/2762)

2- If your pallet depend on an account (consumers) or may need the existence of this account for the pallet own purposes (sufficients).

See this previous StackExchange answers for more detailed explanations:

- [What is the meaning of the account provider, sufficients and consumer?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/263/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-account-provider-sufficients-and-consumer)
- [Do assets (from the asset pallet on State[mine/mint]) have an existential deposit?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5917/do-assets-from-the-asset-pallet-on-statemine-mint-have-an-existential-deposi)